# Is there a code version for the Quantum Mean Approximation algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-phase-estimation, topological-quantum-computing

I found this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4267.pdf which describes a method to find the mean of all numbers in a list using a quantum algorithm. However, all it gives is the math behind it. Is there code somewhere?
Thank you!